# how to push selected radio buttons options to an array in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I am trying to build a quiz which shows one question per slide dynamically. I wanted to let remain the selected answers as is when I click on next/previous question. I tried the following code. This is is returning NaN when trying to get the values from the array also, the length of the array is increasing even I go forward and backward among the slides. Can any one please help -

```
function choose() {
    console.log("selection -"+$('input[name="answer"]:checked').val())
    selections[questionCounter] =+ $('input[name="answer"]:checked').val();
    console.log("selections - "+selections[questionCounter])  
  }
```

full code here - https://jsfiddle.net/fqrhuo23/

Comment: `=+` should be `+=` - although that line should just be `selections[questionCounter] = $('input[name="answer"]:checked').val();` and it works fine.  (offtopic: you might want to review question 4)

Comment: Instead of doing `selections[questionCounter] += $('input[name="answer"]:checked').val();`, you can simply push in the array `selects.push($('input[name="answer"]:checked').val();)`

Comment: @YoannPicquenot that won't work as user can go back so if you answered question 1,2 then back to 1, you'd get `[a,b,a]` instead of `[a,b]`

Comment: @freedomn-m gotchu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

instead of using

```
selections[questionCounter] =+ $('input[type="radio"]:checked').val();
```

You need to use

```
selections[questionCounter] = $('input[type="radio"]:checked').val();
```

Since you already initiated `selections` as `[]`. `selections[questionCounter] = $('input[type="radio"]:checked').val();` will create corresponding array index for you. When you are using `+` in front of the value, which is trying to cast `$('input[type="radio"]:checked').val()` to a number. You are trying to cast a string type to number. That's why you are getting `NaN`.

```js
console.log(+"a");
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the valuable explanation. As i am still learning this background is what I needed.